# Reading data from server in apollo resolver

Tags: graphql, apollo

So I have resolver for managing my local state during authentication which updates current user.

```
updateCurrentUser: (_, { username, password }, { cache }) => {
  const LOGIN = gql`
        query Authenticate($username: String!, $password: String!){
          authenticate(username: $username, password: $password) {
            username
            token
          }
        }`
  const login = server.readQuery({ query: LOGIN, variables: {username: username, password: password} })
  if (login === null) {
    cache.writeQuery({
      query: gql`
      query GetLoginError {
        loginError @client {
          error
        }
      }`,
      data: {
        loginError: {
          error: 'wrong loing data'
        }
      }
    })
  }
  else {
    const newData = {
      currentUser: {
      ...login
    }}
    cache.writeQuery({ query: GET_CURRENT_USER, data: newData })
  }
  return null;
}
```

Obviously 9th row is wrong but I haven't found any feasible way to perform call to server during mutation of local state without performing some weird hacks. What would be proper way to do it?

update:
Is there at least any good way to update local state right after mutation to server?